# Pendrive not detecting after formatting disk utility

Tags: mount, usb-drive

After running `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc40dc40d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        3824    30716248+   7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda2            3825       19341   124639233    5  Extended
/dev/sda4           19342       19457      927734   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda5            3825       19341   124639232   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 8011 MB, 8011120640 bytes
247 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1021 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 15314 * 512 = 7840768 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ee4ed

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

I can't find /dev/sdb*

Comment: deepa, you can use code tags when posting terminal output. It will look prettier and also will be easier to read.

Comment: You're not really asking a question, and what do you mean by "can't find /dev/sdb*"?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a pendrive with a corrupt partition table. I used Gparted to rewrite the partition table.

Gparted, Device menu, Create partition table.